# jQuery is not defined when register a older jQuery Version in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, defined

For an old Wordpress Plugin I need an older jQuery version.

So I thought I could deregister the preregistered jQuery from Wordpress and register a Library from Google CDN.

In the functions.php file I added these lines:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'new_jquery_enque_func' );
function new_jquery_enque_func()
{
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.3/jquery.min.js', false);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

When I reload the WP-Admin Page I get many of these Errors in several Files:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

What can I do to get this to work right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not supposed to use another jQuery library. The jQuery library in WordPress is loaded in [No Conflict mode](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries) to prevent issues with other libraries you might be using.

So, by default you should use `jQuery` instead of `$`. WordPress plugins also use `jQuery` in their code. Unregistering WordPress jQuery will cause the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

If you still want to use the `$` inside your jQuery code, you can use [noConflict Wrappers](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers) like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // use $() inside!
});
```

The WordPress dashboard relies on the inbuilt jQuery version. If you really want to change jQuery, you can change it only on your theme using something like:

```
if( ! is_admin() ){
  add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'new_jquery_enque_func' );
  function new_jquery_enque_func()
  {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js', false);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
  }
}
```

I might also add that `jQuery 1.7.3` does not exist. `jQuery 1.7.2` exists though, unless you confused with `jQuery UI 1.7.3`

Comment: The Plugin that I use is very important. And its no longer supported by the developer. Since the last update of wordpress with new jQuery version the Plugin doesn't work anymore. Is there no chance to get this done?

Comment: Are you sure it is the new jQuery version that is causing that?

Comment: For example: there are functions in the WP-Admin Plugin Settings for adding or edit items. To edit an item you click on it and it will (jquery function) slide down to open the item. This doesn't work now. It worked until I updated wordpress, so I'm pretty sure that a new jQuery version is causing that.

Comment: Thank you for your support RRikesh. I discovered the problem in a different place and fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Your reference URL doesn't seem to be working..

It might be remove from the server, so better try latest.

[**Check**](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.3/jquery.min.js)

*It has an error*

Find some other URL or migrate to newer version **1.9.1** .

[**New Version**](//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js)